# Push changes to connected apps

Tags: integration, connected-apps, notification

Does Salesforce support pushing changes to integrated services?

Im creating integration from our system to Salesforce and we use products, users can create orders from our system so product data must always be up to date. Of course we can always fetch the product data when order is being created, but then there would be huge amount of requests, or sync product data every minute or so, but then there is always that cap.

So I was thinking maybe Salesforce can send "please update" request to specified URL so our system knows that now we need to sync product data with SF.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes it can do that

Comment: Ok, thanks, can you eloborate a bit? Im struggling to find anything from the docs.

Comment: Simplest way - outbound messages

Answer (score 0):

Will add more detail later but seems like what you are looking for is

[Outbound Messaging](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_om_outboundmessaging_understanding.htm)